# Call onClick React function from html

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, bing-maps

I use a Bing Map with a custom infobox on it. The infobox also contains custom close icon which I want to perform a close function.
I already tried multiple ways but the clearInfoBox function is not executed.

```
clearInfoBox() {
   console.log("test");
}

var infoboxTemplate = 
 `<div style="margin-top:0px; margin-left:20px;">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="{this.clearInfoBox}"><img style="float: right;" src="${closeIcon}"/></a>
  </div>`

this.centerOfSearchInfoBox = new window.Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(new window.Microsoft.Maps.Location(this.centerOfSearch.latitude, this.centerOfSearch.longitude), {
    htmlContent: infoboxTemplate,
  });

  this.centerOfSearchInfoBox.setMap(map);
```

Comment: Is the question how to call the function `clearInfoBox()` when clicking the close icon, and is that a function you try to call from `this.clearCenterOfSearchInfoBox`? If so, the normal problem is that you haven't binded `this.clearCenterOfSearchInfoBox` to this, so `this` in `onClick` is the html element not your object

Comment: sorry was a copy past mistake I want to call clearInfoBox() when clicking on the close icon

Comment: Since you use `this` I assume you are in a class. In the constructor you need to add `this.clearInfoBox = this.clearInfoBox.bind(this)` or change `onClick` to be `onClick="{this.clearInfoBox.bind(this)}"` to get reference to the correct `this` in the event

Comment: Methods are not bound by default. If you forget to bind this.clearInfoBox and pass it to onClick, this will be undefined when the function is actually called.

Comment: Yes I'm in a class. When I try `onClick="{this.clearInfoBox.bind(this)}` I get `Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick` and when I try to bind it in the constructor like `this.clearInfoBox.bind(this);` then call it like: `onClick="{this.clearInfoBox}` nothing happen

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your clearInfoBox function into a constant. This way you will not need to bind it in the constructor.

Then pass it as a prop to your template variable.

The code should look something like this:

```
clearInfoBox = () => {
   console.log("test");
}

const infoboxTemplate = (clearFn) => 
 `<div style="margin-top:0px; margin-left:20px;">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick={clearFn}><img style="float: right;" src="${closeIcon}"/></a>
  </div>`

this.centerOfSearchInfoBox = new window.Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(new window.Microsoft.Maps.Location(this.centerOfSearch.latitude, this.centerOfSearch.longitude), {
    htmlContent: infoboxTemplate(this.clearInfoBox),
  });

this.centerOfSearchInfoBox.setMap(map);
```

Also, do not use quotes around onChange handlers.

Comment: @WeSt try to change onClick to: `onClick={${clearFn}}`

Comment: doesn't break anymore but the function is also not executed

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you.
First in html `onclick` not `onClick`

```
var infoboxTemplate = 
 `<div style="margin-top:0px; margin-left:20px;">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="onClickInfor()"><img style="float: right;" src="${closeIcon}"/></a>
  </div>`
```

And add `onClickInfor` method

```
constructor() {
  ...
  window.onClickInforBox = this.clearInfoBox.bind(this)
}
```

and remove `onClickInforBox` when component unmount

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  window.onClickInforBox = undefined
}
```